# Ubuntu not working after upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 on ASUS U36S

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, upgrade, laptop, asus

I have an ASUS U36S, and no problems using Ubuntu 11.10.

Few hours ago, i upgraded to 12.04 and now nothing works (neither mouse nor almost nothing) I can reboot the system and sometimes the keyboard seems to be more or less configured, so i can type some commands in terminal "F2" (don't know why not in the first one, e.g.) and other times, i can't even login using another terminal but the graphic interface. Anyway, login by this interface, i can't get to execute anything using a terminal into this one.

Should i try to go back to 11.10? Any other solution known? :S

Thanks in advance to any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and solved it by:
- Getting to a command prompt
- running sudo apt-get install -f (it complained that two packages needed to be installed, then configured them and a ton of others)
- rebooting

Looks like these two packages (libjpeg-something and some other) failed to install, so anything dependent on then was not configured properly.

Now everything seems to work ok.

Comment: It almost did it; some icons and the mouse are again working, but i still have a problem with the keyboard configuration; by default it starts with the NumLk activated. Anyway, a big step. Thanks; right answer for me ;)